# "The service encountered an error. Please try again later" error message while sharing Image on Tumblr

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using sharekit for login into Tumblr and also Sharing Image on Tumblr. Its works fine few days ago but now it gives and error message "The service encountered an error. Please try again later", When i m trying to share an Image or login into Tumblr.

can anybody help me. ??

Answer (score 0):

It can happen only because may be the network you are using is not working. Or may be the server to which you are calling the web services or login service is not responding. check your server is working and your internet connection is working properly or not..

Comment: My net connection is properly working. and I am not using any Webservice, I am using Sharekit, The sharekit uses internally Tumblr API. But this error cant be resolved